# How to Solve payfort response_message=failed to check fraud screen

Tags: android, payment, gateway, payfort

i am using amazone payment gateway (`payfort sdk`) in my `andorid` application and getting
error `"failed to check fraud screen"` in response message

```
 
 private FortRequest getFortRequest(String token,String signature) {
         Log.e(TAG, "getFortRequest token: " + token);
         FortRequest fortRequest = new FortRequest();
         Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
         hashMap.put("command", "AUTHORIZATION");
         hashMap.put("customer_email", "testuser@gmail.com");
         hashMap.put("currency", "SAR");
         hashMap.put("amount", "100");
         hashMap.put("language", "en");
         hashMap.put("merchant_reference", "XYZ9236-ynm898");
         hashMap.put("customer_name", "Ramesh kumar");
         hashMap.put("customer_ip", "112.196.1.218");
         hashMap.put("payment_option", "MASTERCARD");
         hashMap.put("eci", "ECOMMERCE");
         hashMap.put("order_description", "DESCRIPTION");
         hashMap.put("sdk_token", token);
         fortRequest.setRequestMap(hashMap);
         return fortRequest;
     }
 
  FortRequest request = getFortRequest(token,signature);
             request.isShowResponsePage();
             FortSdk.getInstance().registerCallback(this,
                     request,
                     FortSdk.ENVIRONMENT.TEST,
                     5,
                     fortCallBack,
                     true,
                     new FortInterfaces.OnTnxProcessed() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCancel(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> map1) {
                     Log.e(TAG, "onCancel: " + map1.toString());
                 }
 
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> map1) {
                     Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess:map " + map.toString());
                     Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess:map1 " + map1.toString());
                 }
 
                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> map1) {
                     Log.e(TAG, "onFailure:map " + map.toString());
                     Log.e(TAG, "onFailure:map1 " + map1.toString());
                 }
             });
```

E/paytag: onFailure:map1 {amount=100,
response_code=10078, card_number=512345******2346, card_holder_name=Ramesh Kumar,
payment_option=MASTERCARD, order_description=DESCRIPTION, expiry_date=2505,
customer_ip=112.196.1.218, eci=ECOMMERCE, language=en, fort_id=169996200005502088,
command=AUTHORIZATION, response_message=failed to check fraud screen,
sdk_token=1fea904f6ee3466a949f01761cb26f20, merchant_reference=XYZ9236-ynm898,
customer_email=testuser@gmail.com, currency=SAR, customer_name=Ramesh kumar, status=10}

Answer (score 0):

i have resolve this by contacting with amazone customer care
There is something pending with test account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).